# How I can get correct page-numbering?

Tags: page-numbering, chapters

Writing a text into chapters, when compiling, the pages of each chapter are numbered starting from number 1, although in the PDF displays the correct total page of text.
At the beginning of each chapter use commands

```
\begin{titlepage} 
\chapter{Notes xxxxxx} 
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: The `titlepage` environment resets the page number. What do you need it for? It's rather uncommon to have only the title in the chapter starting page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `titlepage` environment to reset your page numbering. Instead, and this is only a minimal example yet it produces chapter start-pages numbered 1:

```
\documentclass{report}
\let\oldclearpage\clearpage% Save \clearpage
\let\oldchapter\chapter% Save \chapter
\renewcommand{\chapter}{% Update \chapter macro
  \renewcommand{\clearpage}{% Update \clearpage
    \oldclearpage\pagenumbering{arabic}% Reset page numbering
    \let\clearpage\oldclearpage}% Restore \clearpage
  \oldchapter}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Second chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\chapter{Last chapter}
\lipsum[1-50]
\end{document}
```

You may have problems if you're using [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).